# Can I make Mercurial set windows login id as username automatically

Tags: mercurial

I looking for a way to set automatically the windows login id as username, so any user that clones my repository won't have to write his own username, but when he clones my repository he will get as username his windows login id automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can configure the `mercurial.ini` (`C:\user\yourUsuario\mercurial.ini`), not to be asked for User and password for each `clone`, `pull`, `push`, etc. To this end:

```
[auth]
hg.prefix = mercurialAddress
hg.username = user
hg.password = pass
hg.schemes = http
```

Or this way to make the clone:

```
hg clone http:\\user:pass@mercurialAddress/Folder/repository
```

---

<sup>*translated by google translate.*</sup>

Comment: In case there is a misunderstanding, I want to create a repository and whoever clones my repository don't have to declare his username; I want Mercurial to automatically use each pc's windows login id.
I hope that's more clear.

Comment: I understood, but I do not know if it's possible.

Comment: I tried placing the mercurial with anonymous access permission, and it worked, I could not do it specifically in a repository, there might be a way to do that.